# Series Convergence Using The Cauchy Condensation Test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Prove that $\sum_{x=2}^{\infty}\frac{(\log x)^{j}}{x^P} $ converges for $j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $j \geq 1 $, and $p \in\mathbb{R} $ and $ p > 1 $.

I've tried solving this problem by using the Cauchy Condensation Test and it yields the correct results. However, one requirement of the test is that the sequence be monotonically decreasing. Though I am aware that this is correct because I checked the graph, I am unsure about how I can actually prove it (without using differentiation). So, how should I go about showing that each term is less than the previous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using *asymptotic analysis*:

Observe that $\;1<\frac{p+1}2<p$ and rewrite the general term of this series:
$$\frac{\log^jn}{n^p}=\frac{\log^j n}{n^{\tfrac{p-1}2+\tfrac{p+1}2}}=\frac{\log^j n}{n^{\tfrac{p-1}2}}\,\frac{1}{n^{\frac{p+1}2}}=o\Biggl(\frac{1}{n^{\frac{p+1}2}}\Biggr)$$
since for any $j$ and any $\alpha >0$, we have $\log^jn=o\bigl(n^\alpha\bigr)$, and the $p$-series $\;\displaystyle\sum_n\frac{1}{n^{\frac{p+1}2}}$ converges.

Comment: Sorry for being unaware, but what is "asymptotic analysis" and is there any good resource you can recommend for studying it?

Comment: It's all about the relative behaviour of functions in the neighbourhood of a point or at infinity, and the notions of *equivalent* functions (their ratio tends to $1$) little o (the  ratio tends to $0$ or big O (the ratio is bounded). Usually, you see the premises in high school (of course without saying so) when you learn that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x}=0$ ($\log x$ is $o(x)$) or $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ ($\sin x\sim_0 x$). You can see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis). for that

Comment: Alright. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is easy to prove without differentiation, however, it is very easy to show that $f(x) = \frac{\log (x)^{j}}{x^{p}}$ is decreasing after some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ (Note, not immediately) using it:
$$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} = x^{-p - 1} \cdot \log(x)^{j - 1}(j - p \cdot \log(x))$$
So when $p \cdot \log(x) > j$ (such $x$ exist because $log(x)$ monotonically increases), the deriative will be negative, and that means that the function is decreasing.
You might try to prove it without differentiation, by looking at $f(x + 1) - f(x), x\in \mathbb{N}$, and trying to see for which $x$ the difference is negative.
Also, the series in which you are interested are called Bertrand Series. The easiest way to prove your question is by applying the [integral test for convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence), it basicaly means that if $f(x)$ is positive and monotonically decreasing(which we have proved), than $\sum\limits_{i = k}^{\infty} f(i) \text{ converges} \Leftrightarrow \int\limits_{k}^{\infty} f(x) dx \text{ converges}$.
And convergence of the integral is trivial for $p > 1, j \ge 1$.
Also, in fact you don't need the conditions on $j$, if $p > 1$ than the series will converge for any $j$.